# How to make a command based logging console in Java

Tags: java

So I am a self taught developer and Input and Output streams are some of my weakest subjects. I want to make a console based server program that will eject an output log of events happening between itself and a client and at the same time allow input directly from the console window for commands (like "stop" or "update" or any other command I want to add). All my tests with Scanner's and System.in and System.out and the Console Class itself have yielded nothing and I can't find a shred of information on youtube, google, or this website. Can someone help me out here? It would be really appreciated as this is the only thing stopping me from writing my first full program.

thread 1

```
public class Main {

public static volatile boolean running = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console console = System.console();
    MainThread mainThread = new MainThread();
    mainThread.start();
    System.out.println("Thread 1 Started");


    while(running){
        String s = console.readLine("%n>","%n" );
        if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
            running = false;
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You said: " + s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Program Stopping...");
}
```

thread 2

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainThread.class.getName());

public MainThread(){

}


@Override
public void run(){


    while(Main.running){
        log.info("Example Log Output");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some server side code to give you an idea:

```
final Socket client = serverSocket.accept(); //will set the client variable to whoever connects
final ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream()); //for getting client's input
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); //for sending objects to the client

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //for reading in from server's console

String input;
while((input = stdIn.readLine()) != null) { //will read in from console
    out.writeObject(input); //will send console output to connected client
}
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Object objIn;
        while(!client.isClosed()) {
            if((objIn = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("From client: " + objIn.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

And here is the code the client needs:

```
Socket connection = new Socket(host, port); //connect to the server
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); //for sending objects to the server
out.flush();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //for getting server's input

Object input;
while(!connection.isClosed()) { //will only cycle through if connection is open
    if((input = in.readObject()) != null) { //checks if we actually got an object
        System.out.println("Input from server: " + input.toString()); //print out server's console input
    }
}
```

It's obviously not completed exactly to your code, so it needs to be adapted. But the essentials work.

Comment: I appreciate the fast response but that isn't precisely what I was looking for, I need the input and log output to be on the same console window for my server side only, client side is going to be a swing application, any console associated with it would probably just be done using swing Jpanes. I simply do not know where to begin to create a console based program that will show log output and accept user input at the same time like a video game console might do. I have seen it done and I know it is more then possible I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: I have been looking into this problem more for the last 2 hours, still not finding an answer but I have learned that what I am trying to do is separate the StdOut(System.out) and StdIn(System.in) for the purposes of one console in the same application. Something I think is a basic thing but I am having zero luck finding an explanation on how to go about doing it.

Comment: So, you want the StdIn from the client to be sent to the server have both be displayed in one serverside console?

Comment: Negative, I want the StdIn from the server side console to always be displayed below the StdOut on the server side console. Currently I can have 2 seperate threads on the server program, 1 is a scanner waiting for console input (or I can use the Console class) and the second thread is a recurring loop I am using that is just sending out log entries every 10 seconds, the output from the logger keeps overlapping the scanner and if you type something in and a log entry gets shot out, it writes over what you are typing. I will edit the main post with the code itself so you can see what I mean.